Beamer strange interaction between fragile, standalone and new frame option
I am playing with beamer and I wrote a frame option optionA to change locally the background.
I also want to put some part of my document in a standalone, so I create another named part.tex included in a main.tex and to make sure that they are sharing the same preamble I put it into a dedicated file header.tex.
Up to there, no problem.
But, when I try to include code in my frames using fragile frame option, things are getting weird.
First, in the standalone compilation of part.tex the background is modified after using optionA even on frames that do not have this option.
Such things are not occurring without fragile option.
Second, the compilation of main.tex is yielding a ! Emergency stop and no log file is generated.
So, I don't know how to debug such situation.
Here is my MWE:

header.tex

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{testBG}{
   \includegraphics{example-image-a}
}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\bool_new:N \l_varA
\bool_set_false:N \l_varA

\define@key{beamerframe}{optionA}[true]{
    \bool_set_true:N \l_varA
    \begingroup
        \setbeamertemplate{background~canvas}[testBG]
}
\apptocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{
    \bool_if:NTF \l_varA {
        \endgroup
        \bool_set_false:N \l_varA
    }{}
}{}{}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff


part.tex

\documentclass{beamer}

\input{header.tex}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]{first frame}
        fragile frame with code 
      \begin{verbatim}\logo{}\end{verbatim}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[optionA]{second frame}
        frame with a varA background
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[optionA, fragile]{third frame}
        ERROR in main: ! Emergency stop.
         
        frame with a varA background and with fragile code:
        \begin{verbatim}\logo{}\end{verbatim}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{fourth frame}
        ERROR in part: 
        Here I should get no varA background
    \end{frame}

\end{document}


main.tex

\documentclass{beamer}

\input{header.tex}

\begin{document}

   \input{part.tex}

\end{document}

Does anyone know how to solve such problem ?

Instead of running into problems with the added group, you could reset the background before each frame, e.g. \BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}}

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , yes of course, in this simple example. But in my final applications I have more things happening inside the option definition that I want to keep only active in the frame. So, I would prefer to keep things in an option for simplicity, however, if you have another way than the adding group, I will be glad to see it. And even more if it solves this issue :)

You can keep them in a frame option,  just don't use a group and reset them like this.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hum, ok. Can you explain why and how ? :)

You can avoid the problem if you don't add a group. A couple of alternative ways:
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{header.tex}
\usepackage[group=false]{standalone}
%\usepackage{expl3}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{testBG}{
   \includegraphics{example-image-a}
}


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{optionA}[true]{
   \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[testBG]
}
\makeatother

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{part.tex}
\documentclass{beamer}

\input{header.tex}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]{first frame}
        fragile frame with code 
      \begin{verbatim}\logo{}\end{verbatim}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[optionA]{second frame}
        frame with a varA background
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[optionA, fragile]{third frame}
        ERROR in main: ! Emergency stop.
         
        frame with a varA background and with fragile code:
        \begin{verbatim}\logo{}\end{verbatim}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{fourth frame}
        ERROR in part: 
        Here I should get no varA background
    \end{frame}

\end{document}

\end{filecontents*}

\input{header.tex}

\begin{document}

   \input{part.tex}

\end{document}


\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{header.tex}
\usepackage[group=false]{standalone}
%\usepackage{expl3}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{testBG}{
   \includegraphics{example-image-a}
}


\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{optionA}[true]{
  \thispagestyle{navigation@optionA}
}

\def\ps@navigation@optionA{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[testBG]
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}
}

\makeatother

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{part.tex}
\documentclass{beamer}

\input{header.tex}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]{first frame}
        fragile frame with code 
      \begin{verbatim}\logo{}\end{verbatim}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[optionA]{second frame}
        frame with a varA background
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[optionA, fragile]{third frame}
        ERROR in main: ! Emergency stop.
         
        frame with a varA background and with fragile code:
        \begin{verbatim}\logo{}\end{verbatim}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{fourth frame}
        ERROR in part: 
        Here I should get no varA background
    \end{frame}

\end{document}

\end{filecontents*}

\input{header.tex}

\begin{document}

   \input{part.tex}

\end{document}


I will try these solutions. However, I can see that the first solution is a brutal since it does not give the possibility to reset the template in the middle of the presentation (because hard coded at every new frame). On the other hand, I don't know and don't understand how this navigation tricks are working. Could you, please, develop a bit your answer on this point ?

@R.N You can still overwrite the default template in the middle of the presentation, e.g. \BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}} If you need even more fine control, use hooks.
